# ESXi + VCenter 5.1 Refresh Networks

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, esxi, vcenter

I have a number of ESXi 5.1 hosts on VCentre. I have been consolidating our VMs. Previously we had 2 copies of all our VMs, a test and production, I've now been removing 1 copy of everything as production has been shipped. For various reasons in some cases I have kept the production copy and in others, the test copy. But I want them all on the same network so I have moved anything on production network to testing and then deleted the Production VSwitch on each host.

In VCentre if I go to Inventory -> Networking. The Production network is still there are Inactive and it shows a number of VMs still assigned to it. These VMs are assigned to Testing.

Is there any way to get it to refresh what it shown? They have essentially been duplicated as they are showing under the Testing network as well.

Comment: It is possible that these machines still have a hangover connection to the Production Network. It may not be an error. Best check the VM configs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself.

The VMs have snapshots that are associated with the old networks. Removing those snapshots removes them from the production network.